# Accessing Javascript variable in Stylus in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, coffeescript, stylus

I'm making a game with Meteor and I'm trying to create a grid of random size using S-Grid, where i get the columns variable in Javascript (Coffeescript really) and access them in Stylus.

My .coffee file is in the lib folder and my main.styl file in the client folder.

```
random = (num) ->
  Math.floor Math.random() * num + 1

@cols = random()
@rows = random()

stylus = require('stylus')

stylus(str)
  .set('filename', '../client/main.styl')
  .define 'cols', stylus.nodes.unit(@cols)
  .define 'rows', stylus.nodes.unit(@rows)
  .render (err, css) ->
    if (err)
      throw err
    console.log(css)
    return
```

I get this error while building the application:
`node_modules/stylus/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch/node_modules/lru-cache/test/memory-leak.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules/stylus/node_modules/source-map/test/run-tests.js:1:15: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
node_modules\stylus\node_modules\sax\examples\test.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
node_modules\stylus\node_modules\sax\LICENSE-W3C.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
The pure Stylus grid works fine but i can't seem to be able to set the columns through Javascript.`

---

I define my grid like this

```
.grid
  grid()
   .box
     cells(1, @cols)
```

Where `@cols` is a random number from a javascript variable. If I use a generic number or generate the random number with Stylus it works fine, but i need the JS variable (i use it for other things). I don't know how to make it in .styl and access it in JS.

Answer (score 1):

define this function in a styl file and include it:

```
random(num)
    return math(math(0, 'random') * num + 1, 'floor')
```

Use random in your stylus file as usual.

Comment: I tried that and it works, but the thing is I need the same random number in both Javascript and CSS. So far I have two randoms, one in the coffee file and another in the styl file.

Comment: in javascript, you can read the generated number from the element using jquery

Comment: I've tried to, but S-Grid doesn't generate a property or anything i can access .Not that I've seen, I've been looking with Firefox Developer Tools but nothing so far.